# What steps do I need to take to make this one-to-many relationship into a many-to-many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen some other posts about this but they're dealing with a version of rails that I'm not using (I'm VERY new to rails), and I have this set up:

```
class ProjectModel < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to:user
```

And:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :project_models
```

I need to know what steps I have to take in order to change this into a many-to-many migration.

Notes: This is for a group project and its my part to set it up so that the projects have a list of users assigned to them, and this list needs to be able to have members added to or deleted from, so I'm not sure whether there needs to be a has_and_belongs_to_many or a has_many:through set up.

Any other info that you could give me would be greatly appreciated but since I'm so new to rails I don't even really know how to do this migration (I only know how to do a one-to-many migration using something like AddAuthorRefToBooks authors:references, if we were working with an example like that).

Comment: I suggest reading Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. [Here's a chapter on the subject](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-a_problem_with_the_data_model).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an intermediary Model e.g.

```
class ProjectParticipant
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project
  has_many :project_participants
  has_many :users, through: :project_participants
end

class User
  has_many :project_participants
  has_many :projects, through: :project_participants
end
```

You can start out with the following so it will also generate the migration you need to create the table.

```
rails g model project_participant project:references user:references
```

or the equivalent

```
rails g model project_participant project_id:integer user_id:integer
```

Comment: This is the "has_many: through" method right? I heard someone else say (and this is the source of some of my confusion) that doing so would be bad for setting up the ability to add or delete participants of the projects, something about it 'inserting or deleting rows from the project_participant model, if we're using this case as an example (they had used UserProject instead)

Also, do I need to create some tables within the project_participant models? I remember reading that I have to insert the 'ids' as integers?

Comment: for `many to many` relations you need an intermediary model + table. It's very common and there's nothing bad about it (first time hear that !!!). If for some reason you don't want to delete any row on user_project you can scope your association to `active` and virtually remove a row by flagging it ìnactive`. Frankly I don't know any alternative to this tried and tested modeling. Here's some more info : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Intermediary model + table...? I understand the intermediary model but what about the table? Also active? I'm really sorry, I'm very new and this is the first time this semester I've been introduced to rails, so I only know some of the basics. I'm not even sure how to go about deleting/adding from project_model.user's list (if that's the right way of writing that). I've also been reading the ruby guides for the past couple of days, but really can't make sense of a lot of it.

Comment: that's a little bit out of the scope of a single answer. I suggest you dive in to the documentation and ask a question whenever you hit a wall. however I'll try to add a few hints in the answer later on, I'm AFK for a few hours... oh and here's a fantastic resource to learn all the basics and more : railscasts.com

Comment: But that's what I've been doing for the past couple of days though. Railcasts and reading the rails guide. That's why I'm here in the first place. Don't I need to do a migration of some sort to create a table containing both user_id and project_id? Everyone and everything gives me so many mixed directions I don't know what to even do.

Comment: Also, would it be project_model:references? Like rails g AddUserRefToProjectModels project_model:references? And how would that look in the command line when making the join table? rails g migration project_models? rails g migration CreateProject_Models? rails g migration project_models_join_users? I have no idea....

Comment: It took me much longer than a couple of days to grasp all the intricacies of rails, domain modeling, sql joins etc... Now to go straight to the point you need to create a table project_users (the name doesn't matter) that holds a reference to a project (with project_id) and an reference to user (with user_id) so it can link project to a user. if a user needs to be linked a project  the rails way is to do : Project.find(id).users << User.find(id) that will create a row in the project_users table linking a specific project to a given user. Maybe this user is also involved in another project

Comment: ...so you add him to the other one: `Project.find(other_id).users << User.find(id)` Now imagine if a user had a column project_id, each users could only be linked to one project : therefore the need for a intermediary table ! Now regarding how you create this tables it's up to you. Just to clear out any misunderstanding `rails g model project_participant project:references user:references`is the same as `rails g model project_participant integer user_id:integer`. Hope it helps, and be patient !

Comment: I wrote a quick blog post to teach my students about many-to-many relationships in Active Record(the ORM rails uses) you can check it out [here](http://andrewsunglaekim.github.io/many-actives-to-many-records/)